# Applying sequence of animation on a view

Tags: android, android-animation

is there a simple way to animate a view so that it does one animation after another.

i tried this:

```
button.animate().translationX(500).setDuration(300);
button.animate().translationX(0).setDuration(300).setStartDelay(2000);
```

Comment: You can specify animation set and then apply it to the view.. See this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
button.animate().translationX(500).setDuration(300).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        button.animate().translationX(0).setDuration(300).start();
    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a listener on the first animation so that when it ends, you can start the second animation:

```
    button.animate().translationX(500).setDuration(300).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            button.animate().translationX(0).setDuration(300).start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but i find Vitaly Zinchenko answer simpler

Comment: It's simpler, but it also requires API level 16 to work, whereas an AnimatorListener only requires API level 12.